# Big $O$ approximation for $T(n)=T(n-i)+T(n-(\frac{n}{m}-i))$

Tags: asymptotics, recursion, big-o-notation

I have the following complexity equation: $T(n)=T(n-i)+T(n-(\frac{n}{m}-i))$ with the base case $T(m)=1$.

Is it possible to calculate a big $O$ approximation for such equation? What is the right method to do so?

**Edit:**
I actually need to calculate this equation for any $1\leq{i}<\frac{n}{m}$
so if it is easier to consider $i$ as a constant, such a solution is also helpful.

**Edit 2:**
I think the equation is also missing floor value of $\frac{n}{m}$ so it will be coherent

Comment: I think $i$ should be between $1$ and $\frac{n}{m}$. Or at least $n-m$ should be less than $\frac{n}{m}$. Right?

Comment: yes, thanks for the correction I'll edit the main post

Comment: Thank you. One more thing. Is $m$ constant? As you have mentioned that $T(m) = 1$.

Comment: Is it not required that $i<{n\over m}$ for all n, so $n-{n\over m} + i<n$ would hold for all n?
It would directly imply that $i=1$. I suppose you have meant something else - maybe $i$ depends on $n$? then write it at $i_n$ for clarification.

Comment: @OmG yes let's consider $m$ as a constant. Does that mean the result wouldn't be dependent on $m$?

Comment: @nirshahar I'm not sure I understood your question. $i$ is not depends on $n$

Comment: $T$ is a recursive function. Try to open it a few times with $i=3, m=1, n=5$ and see what happens